# Meaning of "an all (sth.) shop"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeuxluumV5s#t=1m26s

> I've got a wife and two daughters. We're all huge Disney fans. In fact, in the year 2000 we all moved down to Florida where I was one of five network designers at Walt Disney World which, by the way, at that time was an **all Cisco shop** when it came to routers and switches.

What exactly does this expression mean?

Comment: Cisco equipment was used exclusively there, no other manufacturer's routers and switches. You might see the pattern hyphenated, "all-CISCO", "all-IBM", "all-Linux". Or simply without "all". *We were a DEC shop". "Shop" is like the **shop** in "woodshop" or "bodyshop". Here it is networking or IT shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Shop" is a way to refer to the place where you work, or where a specific type of work is carried out. Refer to these definitions (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**shop**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shop)
>   *Noun*
>
> **2** *[usually with modifier]* A place where things are manufactured or
>   repaired; a workshop:
>   *"an auto repair shop"*
>
> > **2.1** A room or department in a factory where a particular stage of
> >     production is carried out:
> >     *"the machine shop"*
> >
> > **2.2** (**the shop**) *informal* The place where one works:
> >     *"she pointed to the classroom ceiling—'I live here, over the shop.'"*

By extension, "shop" can be used as a [metonym](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/metonym) for the company itself, or a department of the company that is based in the place that is the "shop."

[Cisco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Systems) is a company that makes networking and telecoms equipment.

As @TRomano says, the *all-(sth.)* pattern is used to indicate that *(sth.)* is used exclusively, or that the thing being talked about is completely *(sth.)*. It doesn't necessarily apply just to equipment, but can also apply to characteristics such as colour, gender/sex, and others:

> - [IBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM) has an **all-blue** logo.
> - Wikipedia's [*Films featuring an **all-female** cast*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_featuring_an_all-female_cast) category.
> - "An **all-star** game is an exhibition game that purports to showcase the
>     best players (the 'stars') of a sports league." —[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-star_game)
> - ***All-new*** Hyundai fuel cell SUV confirmed for 2018 
>     —[AutoExpress](http://www.autoexpress.co.uk/hyundai/98187/all-new-hyundai-fuel-cell-suv-confirmed-for-2018)

As @TRomano also says, the *all-(sth.)* pattern isn't required. The *all* part can be omitted, and the meaning will be retained. However, including the *all* part emphasizes the fact that *(sth.)* is used exclusively.

---

> [Walt Disney World] was an all Cisco shop when it came to routers and
>   switches.

What is the speaker is saying, then, is that Walt Disney World exclusively used equipment manufactured by Cisco. The phrase [*when it came to — —*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/when_it_comes_to_%25E2%2580%2594%25E2%2580%2594) limits the equipment the speaker includes in the statement to just routers and [network switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch).

If the *when it came to — —* phrase wasn't used, you'd be free to assume that all networking equipment (not just routers and switches) was manufactured by Cisco, which might include networked telephones or wireless access points as well.